# Hierarchical Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical

I would like to have the following taxonomy structure:

```
site.com/courses/course-name/pathway/pathway-name
```

The domain is such that any particular course can be completed by taking a number of different pathways - different module structures.

The following URLS would work as such:

```
site.com/courses
```

shows a list of courses

```
site.com/courses/course-name
```

will follow a template e.g. single-course.php, showing title, content and a list of the pathways associated to this course.

```
site.com/courses/course-name/pathways/
```

will follow a template e.g. archive-pathway.php, showing course-name and a list of pathways (not be used so much but will still need to work)

```
site.com/courses/course-name/pathways/pathway-name
```

will follow a template, e.g. single-pathway.php, showing the course-name title, the pathway-name title and content for this pathway.

The files here may be incorrect whereby I should be using taxonomy-{}.php or otherwise as appropriate, instead of single-{}.php.

My question: is it possible to set up the above hierarchy within WordPress? If so, please provide some code to `register_taxonomy` or `register_post_type` as appropriate to help me get started.

I cannot find how to do this elsewhere but am pretty sure this is how [courses in the TutsPlus](https://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/vector-portraits-for-beginners/lessons/welcome-course-overview) network use WordPress.

Comment: courses is a post type and pathways is a taxonomy?

Comment: Each pathway needs to have its own content, title, custom fields, featured image etc... don't think this can work as a taxonomy but needs to be a CPT in its own right... but somehow almost as a child of a course CPT..

Comment: you mention taxonomy, but don't appear to be using one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Subordinate Post Type Helpers plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subordinate-post-type-helpers/) to create relationships between two distinct custom post types: `courses` and `pathways`

Answer (score -1):

[image]I'm not entirely sure if this will really help with exactly what you're looking for, but here is the WP template hierarchy. Personally solves a lot of my own questions & is a great reference to look back on